# Javascript modifies the orignal object on using map on a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Consider the following example. An array is contained inside an object and I am using map to modify the contents of the array.

```
let temp = {
    name:'Scott',
    arr: [1, 2, 3, 4],
};

console.log(temp);
let promise = temp.arr.map((obj) => {
return obj*5;
});

Promise.all(promise).then( (temp) => {
    console.log(temp);
});
```

Output is :

```
{ name:'Scott' ,arr: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
[ 5, 10, 15, 20 ]
```

Can someone please explain me why is the original  object modified ?

Comment: Did you realize the arrow function param has the same name as the previously declared variable?

Comment: Just give your variables reasonable names, run it again and also log the original `temp`: http://jsfiddle.net/p682uzov/

Comment: Should it not ideally modify the contents of temp on its own? Or should the modified array be expected as a parameter to the array function on the promise.all

Comment: Mapping through an array of numbers will create a completely new array of numbers not linked to the original reference, if the intended behavior was to mutate the array in the property arr use a simple forEach or for loop to iterate through the items and change their values in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original was never updated, but you changed what `temp` refers to.

Try this instead:

```
Promise.all(promise).then( (result) => {
    console.log("temp", temp);
    console.log("result", result);
});
```

Comment: adding to his answer, the original is not modified. `console.log(temp.arr)` would still resolve to the same array as in the original. The promise returns a new array that has all the mapped values. `.then((temp)=>{});` returns this new array. Change the variable name to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks! this helps!